# Iwasawa main conjectures vs Bloch-Kato conjectures

Tags: iwasawa-theory, galois-representations, galois-cohomology, open-problems, l-functions

Let $p$ be a prime, $K$ be a number field, $S$ a finite set of finite places of $K$ containing the set $S_p$ of places above $p$ and the places at infinity, $G:=G_{K,S}$ the Galois group of the maximal extension of $K$ unramified outside $S$, $\rho: G_K \rightarrow Gl_d({\mathbb Q}_p)$ a geometric irreducible representation of $G_K$.  For $n$ any integer, $\rho(n)$ is the Tate twist of $\rho$, that is $\rho$ tensor the cyclotomic character to the power $n$.

The Bloch-Kato Selmer group of $\rho$, denoted $H^1_f(G,\rho)$ is defined as an explicit subspace of $H^1(G,\rho)$ (continuous cohomology): 
$$H^1_f(G,\rho) = \ker \left(H^1(G,\rho) \rightarrow \prod_{v \in S_K-S_p} H^1(I_v,\rho) \times \prod_{v \in S_p} H^1(D_v, \rho \otimes B_{crys})\right),$$ where $D_v$, $I_v$ are respectively a decomposition subgroup and an inertia subgroup at $v$ of $G$,
and the $\rightarrow$ is the product of the restriction maps.

The first statement of the Bloch-Kato conjecture is (for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$):

CONJECTURE:  $\dim H^1_f(G_K,\rho(n)) - \dim H^0(G_K,\rho(n)) = \text{ord}_{s=1-n} L(\rho^\ast,s).$

Here $L(\rho,s)$ is the complex $L$-function (we assume it has a meromorphic continuation over $\mathbb{C}$)

There are other statements concerning the principal values of the L-function
at $1-n$, that I do not consider here. Note that this conjecture is obviously invariant by Tate twists. Also, the $H^0$ term is $0$ except if $\rho(n)$ is the trivial representation.

Now I come to my question: It is clear that the Iwasawa main conjectures (by which I mean
not only Iwasawa's original conjecture on the Kubota-Leopoldt $\zeta$-function, but its modern generalizations) belongs to the same circle of idea. But what exactly is the
relation?

To make my question more precise, let us consider to fix ideas 
Greenberg's form of the main conjecture, as stated for examples in his paper in Motives.
A condition on $\rho$, called the Panchiskin condition, is needed to formulate the conjecture. Then a Selmer group is defined as a module over the Iwasawa algebra
$\Lambda$, and this module is conjectured to be co-finite and related to the $p$-adic $L$-function of $\rho$. Unfortunately, Iwasawa-theorist tend to use a different language
than Bloch-Kato-theorists: they work with modules like $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and properties like co-finite instead of finite (perhpaps
they are comathematicians). After one takes cohomology, families, etc, the translation between the two languages becomes far from transparent. Yet, I know that the Iwasawa main conjectures have consequences that can be stated in a way very similar to the Bloch-Kato's conjecture.

> Can you state such a consequence of Iwasawa's main conjecture in a language closer to Bloch-Kato, precisely :  relating (probably in a weaker sense that in BK) the dimension of a suitablle Selmer groups defined as a subspace of $H^1(G,\rho(n))$ cut by local conditions with the order of vanishing of the p-adic L-function of $\rho^\ast$ (assuming it exists) at some points ($1-n$?). Or is such a thing written somewhere?

I apologize that my question is at the same time technical and elementary. Yet an answer would help me a lot, and possibly may help other people who want to get a global picture
of this kind of conjectures, and of the progresses made so far. For example, my question contains as a special case:

> What does the Iwasawa main conjecture for ordinary elliptic curces implies for the BSD conjecture?

Comment: Who is a comathematician here ??? :-)

Comment: Perrin-Riou's book on p-adic L-functions is written for general p-adic representations and she has a view on Bloch-Kato.

Comment: The Iwasawa main conjecture for ordinary elliptic curves + the non-degeneracy of the p-adic height + the finiteness of Sha imply the p-adic BSD. To get BSD one would also need that the order of vanishing the complex and the p-adic L-function agree.

Comment: My views, presented here as a few comments rather than an answer, is that Iwasawa theory will always talk about Bloch-Kato type conjectures in a full tower of fields, not just over $K$. And it will be the p-adic rather than the complex L-function.  So with some additional conjectures, Iwasawa main conjectures will say something about Bloch-Kato conjectures, i.e. they are in some way compatible.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comments. Your views are compatible with mine 
:-). Essentially looking at the Selmer group of $\rho$ over the cyclotomic $p$-extensions tower of $K$ is the same thing as looking at the Selmer group of the family of twists of $\rho$ by powers of the cyclotomic character. That's why I formulated Bloch-Kato with integral Tate twists. You Iwasawa-guys twist by more general $p$-adic power of the cyclotomic characters, but in particular specializing at integral twist you shoudl get something looking like Bloch-Kato's conjecture, with a $p$-adic, not complex, $L$-function.



Comment: @Joel:  Thinking about elliptic curves, one reason for looking at Selmer groups of $Q_p/Z_p$-type representations is that these keep track of both Mordell-Weil and Tate-Shafarevich.  I think that such a Selmer group over the cyclotomic $Z_p$-extension of say $Q$ has more information than the Selmer groups of $\rho(n)$ as $n$ varies over $Z$.  Indeed, imagine a situation where the complex $L$-series does not vanish at any integer.  Then the Selmer group of $\rho(n)$ should vanish for all $n$ by Bloch-Kato.  However, there is no need for the $Q_p/Z_p$-Selmer group to vanish.  Indeed, the...

Comment: $p$-adic $L$-function might have its zeroes at some random characters which are not integral powers of the cyclotomic character.  


Comment: I don't think that the Iwasawa MC for ordinary ell. curves implies $p$-adic BSD.  Indeed, as Joel surely knows, there is the problem that the $p$-adic $L$-function could have a double root at $s = 1$, but the Selmer group might still be of rank one (non-semiplicity of the Selmer group of $Q_{\infty}$).   It seems (based on work of Joel with Gaetan Chenevier, and also on annoucned work of Skinner and Urban) that constructing Selmer groups for some fixed $\rho$ of weight one of dimension $> 1$ can be harder than proving the Iwasawa MC.  

Comment: @Rob: You may be right, but I don't understand why it is necessary to work with the $\Q_p/\Z_p$-style Selmer group to see this phenomenon. You can as well twist your representation over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by a non-inetgral power of the cyclotomic character (say a power $x \in Z_p$ congruent to $0 \pmod{p-1}$ to be sure). In your context, wouldn't we see the nonvanishing of the Selmer group of the twisted representation over $Q_p$ as well?   




For example, in your situation, wouldn't we have that 
$H^1(G,\rho^\ast \otimes \omega_p^{x}) \neq 0$, for $\omega_p$ the cyclotomic character, and    

Comment: @Emerton: Yes, I knew this issue that the MC will only implies 
a lower bound of $1$ on "the Selmer group" even if the $p$-adic $L$-functions vanishes as an high order, at least until some conjecture on the semi-simplicty of the Selmer group is solved. But actually, what I don't know is even more basic: what Selmer group are we talking about in this context? 

Comment: @Joel: You would need even more general twists than this -- you would at least need to twist by all characters of $Z_p^\times$. (The zeroes of the $p$-adic $L$-function are just some random characters in weight space.)  With that said, the data of all Selmer groups of $\rho$ twisted by any of these characters is nearly the same as the this $Q_p/Z_p$-Selmer group over the cyclotomic $Z_p$-extension.  The only difference that remains is a $\mu$-invariant.  Indeed, writing down a $Q_p/Z_p$-Selmer group requires a choice of lattice in $\rho$ and this can affect the $\mu$-invariant.

Comment: Dear Joel, I have wondered the same question (what is the relationship between the Bloch--Kato Selmer groups, defined for pst $\rho$, and the more Selmer groups appearing in (say) ordinary Iwasawa theory.   My (perhaps naive) picture was that they were more or less the same, perhaps taking into account issues with exceptional zeroes (whose manifestation on the algebraic side always confuses me).  I also imagined that reading Nekovar, and perhaps Jay Pottharst, would resolve my confusion.  What do they have to say on this issue?

Comment: Dear Matt, reading Jay Pottharst's paper and asking him for explanations when needed is also my hope to resolve my confusion
(if no one here gives me the solution ready-for-use before).

I am not sure that the exceptional zeros are the only issue, at least if by that you mean the exceptional zeros due to the interpolation factor at $p$ as in Mazur-Tate-Teitelbaum. The example I have in mind is $H^1_f(Q,Q_p(k))$ for $k$ negative. Those spaces are known to be zero (Soulé) and this is in perfect harmony with the Bloch-Kato conjecture, since obviously $\zeta(1-k) \neq 0$ (for $1-k > 1$).


  
   

Comment: Yet on the $p$-adic size, things are not as clear. Take $k$ negative as above, and even. Then it is an open question whether $\zeta_p(1-k)$ is $0$ or not. Since the Main Conjecture is known in this case, then
if the main conjecture implies that the non-vanishing of $\zeta_p(1-k)$ is equivalent to the vanishing of a suitable of $Q_p(k)$, this 
suitable Selmer group can't be the $H^1_f$ since this one is known for $Q_p(k)$. Obviously, the relevant Selmer group in this case is the full cohomology group $H^1(Q,Q_p(k))$ whose dimension is not known to be $0$ or $1$ (for $k$ negative even, I recall)

Comment: Dear Joel,

Thanks very much for this example; somehow I was aware of all or most of the fact you recalled, but had never put them together and tried to reconcile them.   I now have to reflect on all this, and on Olivier's answer below.  Best wishes,  Matt

Comment: In his paper in the p-adic mondromy and BSD proceedings, Greenberg conjectures that (if you're H^0=0, so that the order of vanishing of the complex L-function is just conjectured to be the dimension of the H^1_f) the difference in the order of vanishing of the complex L-function and the p-adic L-function is exactly his expected order of the trivial zero of the p-adic L-function. This order is conjecturally a local computation. But yeah I think Jay had some more high brow and general way he could see the contribution of the trivial zero.

Comment: @Rob H. Greenberg conjecture, as you described it, is equivalent to the conjecture that the complex giving the local condition at $p$ are semi-simple. So general believable conjectures imply that the difference in order of vanishing should be exactly what we believe it is. However, I have never heard any of the (big or small) semi-simplicity conjectures described as within reach, so I am not sure this is really good news.  

Comment: Dear Joel, I read the discussion between you and Olivier below his answer, and it was very interesting, and illuminating. I think I understand your question better now. Am I right in thinking that you believe that for each $n$ there is a Selmer condition, call it $\mathcal L_n$, such that the order of vanishing of the $p$-adic $L$-function at $n$ is provably (given the IMC) equal to the dimension of $H^1_{\mathcal L_n}(\mathbb Q,\rho(1−n))$? And that the aim of your question is to get some kind of "formula" for $\mathcal L_n$? 

Comment: Dear Joel, Suppose you can find the correct Selmer condition $\mathcal L_n$ of my previous comment.  Do you think that one could deduce from the IMC that the order of vanishing of the $L$-function at $n$ is precisely equal to the dimension of $H^1_{\mathcal L_n}(\mathbb Q,\rho(1-n))$, or do you think you would just get the weaker statement that the $L$-function vanishes if and only if the Selmer group is non-zero?  (I am worried about non-semi-simplicity again.)

Comment: Ah ... is this what you mean by "probably in a weaker sense than in BK"?

Comment: You have exactly understood what I think -- and made me realize how badly I have explained it in the first place. And that's what I meant by "proably in a weaker sense than in BK".

I have finished my course today, and I will try to read Jay's paper
to see if I can find the correct Selmer condition from it.



Comment: But this is essentially hopeless if you define $H^{1}_{\mathcal L_{n}}(\mathbb\Q,\rho(1-n))$ as a subgroup of $H^{1}$ satisfying certain conditions. How are you going to account for the order of the trivial zeroes? Again, the conjectural framework does not predict that there should be such a Selmer group: it predicts that there should the Euler charcteristic of a complex (which in the end amounts to the dimension of a vector space which admits $H^{1}(\mathbb\Q,\rho)$ as a quotient, not as a superobject). Besides, much of this is known to be true: look at the articles of D.Benois for instance.

Comment: Well, as we already discussed, the order of the p-adic $L$-function
should be dim $H^1_{L_n}(Q,\rho(1-n))$ plus or minus trivial 
terms (e.g. local cohomology groups, or global H^0 i.e. terms computable at glance)

Moreover, the Euler characteristic of a complex is equal to the Euler  characteristic of its cohomology. If you have an explicit complex doing what you say it does, then its Euler characteristic will doubtlessly have the form mentioned in the above paragraph.

If this is known to be true, which I believe too (that's why I asked), can you give me the formula or a precise reference?



Comment: Bien sûr. Indique moi juste une adresse mail valide.

Answer (score 12):

If I understand your question properly, then I think much is known. Let me sum up what I understand about this picture.

First a short answer to your question. Contrary to what you ask for, it is not expected that the dimension of a subspace of $H^{1}$ cut by local conditions should express the order of vanishing of the $p$-adic $L$-function.

Let us start with Bloch-Kato conjecture. This conjecture can be interpreted as a description of cohomological invariants of motives using special values of the $L$-function (many people think of it in the converse way, as description of special values of the $L$-function in terms of Galois invariants). The first question to ask is "which cohomological invariants are we trying to describe?" and the most reasonable answer is "the complex $C$ of motivic cohomology with compact support" (not known to exist in general). Then the order of vanishing of the $L$-function gives the Euler characteristic of $C\otimes_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb R$ whereas the $p$-adic valuation of the principal term of the $L$-function (divided by the period defined in Bloch-Kato) is a $\mathbb Z_{p}$-basis of the determinant of $C\otimes_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb Q_{p}$ (more precisely, of the inverse of the determinant). Even though you knew all this already, I found it necessary to recall it in order to state what forms the IMC takes in this context.

Assume now that our $p$-adic Galois representation $V$ comes from a pure motive and is crystalline at $p$ (I realize that you don't want to make such a strong assumption, but I think all I will say will continue to hold, at least conjecturally). As pointed out in comments already, and as you know, the IMC will say something about the interpolation of the Bloch-Kato conjecture in a $\mathbb Z_{p}$-extension (or more generally in a universal deformation space). I will discuss here only the case of the cyclotomic $\mathbb Z_{p}$-extension. Inside $D_{cris}(V)$ sits $D^{\phi=p^{-1}}$. Let $e$ denotes the dimension of this space over $\mathbb Q_{p}$. Then the cohomological object described by the special values of the (putative) $p$-adic $L$-function is the Selmer complex $S$ of $V$ with the unramified conditions at places $\ell≠p$ of ramifications of $V$ and with the Bloch-Kato condition *at the level of complex* at $p$.

Based on Bloch-Kato, we should thus expect the Euler characteristic of $S$ evaluated at a character (this is to say of $S\otimes_{\Lambda}\mathbb Z_{p}[\chi]$) to be the order of vanishing of the $p$-adic $L$-function and the $p$-adic $L$-function to give a basis of $\det_{\Lambda} S$. Alas, things are not so easy, because of the infamous trivial zeroes phenomena. So what you can show (possibly assuming plausible conjectures or restricting yourself to rank at most 2 along the way, I'll make an effort to state something really precise if you need to) is that, under Bloch-Kato, the Euler characteristic of $S\otimes_{\Lambda}\mathbb Z_{p}[\chi]$ is equal to the order of vanishing of the usual $L$-function twisted by $\chi$ (as expected) plus $e$ (this is the contribution of the trivial zeroes) $\textit{provided}$  the $\mathcal L$-invariant does not vanish (this is, or should be, equivalent to the semi-simplicity of the complex giving the local condition at $p$).

All this having been said, perhaps you want a concrete answer for a concrete representation. In that case, nothing is simpler than a brave old ordinary representation. For ordinary representation, the local condition at $p$ for the Selmer complex $S$ is simply $R\Gamma(G_{\mathbb Q_{p}},V)$. Hence, the order of vanishing of the $p$-adic $L$-function at a given $\chi$ should simply be the order of vanishing of the $L$-function plus the dimension of $H^{0}(G_{\mathbb Q_{p}},V^{*}(1)/F^{+}V^{*}(1))$ plus or minus simple terms (like the zeroes or poles of the Gamma factors). This reflects the fact that in the generic case, the order of vanishing of the $p$-adic $L$-function should be the dimension of the first cohomology of $S$ (which is not a subspace of $H^{1}$, hence my word of warning at the beginning).

Hope this helped somehow.

Now, let us move on to your second question. I think that if you knew only the IMC, then you couldn't say much about the order of vanishing part of Bloch-Kato. However, if you knew the IMC as well as non-degeneracy of the $p$-adic height pairing (required to formulate the Equivariant Tamagawa Number Conjecture) as well as the Equivariant Tamagawa Number Conjecture for each layer of the cyclotomic extension and/or the vanishing of the $\mu$-invariant, then the order part of Bloch-Kato would follow. Here is how I would try to prove this. First, I would define $S$ (no problem here,as we are in the ordinary case). Then I would construct a canonical trivialization of this complex at each finite layer using the non-degeneracy of the height pairing. Then I would use the ETNC (or I would deduce the ETNC from the IMC using the vanishing of the $\mu$-invariant) to show that the image of the determinant of $S$ at a finite layer under my canonical trivialization is really the value of the principal term of the analytic $L$-function (perhaps times the $\mathcal L$-invariant, but I would know this to be non-zero by semi-simplicity of my complexes). In this way, I would manufacture a complex $L$-function which would agree with the ordinary $L$-function at many (not necessarily classical) points (this would presumably require the IMC and ETNC not only for the cyclotomic extension but for the Hida family containing $E$) and would thus be equal to it. Now, I would know the order of vanishing of my algebraic complex $L$-function at a classical point, so I would know the order of vanishing of the complex $L$-function as well so (finally!) I could check Bloch-Kato.

So, yeah, if you knew the ETNC for the full Hida family and/or the vanishing of the $\mu$-invariant plus the non-degeneracy of the $p$-height pairing, you can, I think, collect the order part of Bloch-Kato as a bonus. Perhaps a moment of sober reflexion is in order now.

Again, hope this helped (but doubt it somehow).

Comment: Thanks very much to you Olivier for your long answer. Point taken
about the fact that the dimension we're looking for may be not the dimension of a subspace of a full global H^1, but rather may hace correcting local terms as well. 

Yet, your answer is not exactly what I was looking for, but that's my fault as I realized (after all this discussion) that I didn't ask my question clearly enough. Let me explain what I am really looking for (this is also an answer to Rob H's recent comment under my question):



Comment: It is important here to be careful about the difference between
well-believed conjectures and unconditional results. What I am looking for is a result that satisfies two conditions:
1) it relates the vanishing (or not) of a $p$-adic L-function
of a Galois representation $\rho$ (defined however you like) at an
integer $n$, with the dimension of a Selmer group of $\rho^\ast(1-n)$ plus corrective local terms. 
2) it is an *unconditional* consequence of the main conjecture (in the sense of Greenberg, or more generally Pottharst) relating the p-adic L-function of (1) with an Iwasawa Selmer module.

Comment: To explain this, let me consider the same example as above:
the representation $\Q_p(k)$ of $G_Q$ for $k$ negative even.
In this case, the relevant $p$-adic $L$-function is Kubota-Leopoldt's $\zeta_p$, and your answer becomes: "Grenberg conjectures that there is an equivalence (E) : $H^1_f(Q,Q_p(k)) = 0$ iff $\zeta_p(1-k) \neq 0$"; since the LHS is known, Greenberg conjectures the RHS. Yet the RHS is not known. Hence the equivalence (E) is not known either. Thus (E) can not possibly be a consequence of the main conjecture, because the main conjecture is known in this context by Mazur-Wiles.

Comment: In other words, your answer (E) satisfies condition (1), but not (2).
It is not a consequence of the main conjecture alone, but it is the consequence of the main conjecture, plus another conjecture, namely the non-annulation of a $p$-adic regulator. 

In other words again, (E) is nice and interesting, but it is not an
answer to the question "what does the main conjecture says about the
dimension of a Selmer group, or the vanishing of the $p$-adic L-function?" It is an answer to the more vague question "what do we expect to be true". Yet I believe that the orignal question has a
simple answer.


Comment: Well then, as I wrote already, I think the answer to the question "what does the main conjecture say about the dimension of a Selmer group, or the vanishing of the p-adic L-function?" is "not much".

Comment: Yet I also think that your point of view on this is slightly misguided in the following sense: the modern (and correct) way to look at the IMC is to see it as a generalization (or interpolation, if you wish) of the ETNC at each classical point and each finite layer. In order to formulate the ETNC in this generality, you need as a pre-requisite something like Bloch-Kato's conjecture on the order of vanishing (or something like the non-vanishing of the $p$-adic regulator or something like the semi-simplicity of some complexes).

Comment: In the real world, this crucial input is given to us (at some good classical points) by automorphic considerations which are outside of what we have discussed up to now so we can boot-strap the process to formulate an IMC (and even sometimes prove it, again by the same boot-strapping process). However, this should not obscure the fact that in the grand web of what we expect, the IMC comes very last. It would be marvellous if this boot-strapping process could give us a missing piece, but I don't see that this happened ever outside of the generic case (i.e minimal order of vanishing).

Comment: I would, of course, be extremely interested to be proven wrong. Also, I start to have some sympathies for BCrd style of MO comment. Who needs vowels, when the price to pay is 4 comments in a row? 

Comment: One very last thing, and then I shut up for good, though I have immense respect for Jay's mathematical achievements (and a great fondness towards the character), I don't think he would be too offended if I point out that relating p-adic L-functions with Iwasawa modules was done in considerable generality by B.Perrin-Riou when he was still in high-school. The sentence "in the sense of Greenberg, or more generally Pottharst" makes me cringe a little.  

Comment: I am happy to have this discussion. Olivier, I strongly disagree with you when you say
"in the grand web of what we expect, the IMC comes very last".
The history shows the exact contrary. For the Kubota-Leopoldt's zeta function the IMC (the original one) has been known for more than twenty-five years. Yet we don't know today if $\zeta_p(1-k)$ vanishes for $k$ even negative, nor if $H^1(G_Q,\Q_p(k))=0$. For the the Zeta function of a totally real field, the IMC is known sine 1990, but the Leopoldt's conjecture is still open, maybe for a 
long long time. Etc.





Comment: Now I know why you say that, and this is because of Perrin-Riou's point of view, where indeed the IMF comes last, in a form where
Mazur and Wiles, let alone Iwasawa, would find hard to recognize
the link to what they have done. I like Perrin-Riou a lot,
and I have immense respects for her mathematical achievements, which have provided us with a clear picture of what is expected, but to my sense her point of view has the shortcoming of entangling the accessible-very-hard conjectures (e.g. the IMF or Bloch-Kato) with the inaccessible ($p$-adic Beilinson, etc.).  

Comment: You are right about this entangling business. But the morale of this story (to me) is that as far as I know, the boot-strapping process I alluded too above (which could be summed up as "prove the ETNC in some situations where it is relatively easy then show that it is enough to prove the IMC then show that this proves the ETNC in harder cases as well") has never shed any light on the part we missed in the first place. By the way, you consider Bloch-Kato accessible? In high ranks as well? This surprises me a little. And why are we writing in English? 

Comment: Still, thanks to your question and the ensuing discussion, I just realized that the full ETNC in the anticyclotomic direction for an automorphic form attached to a definite quaternion algebra should be at the very limit of what is accessible nowadays. Perhaps I should look into it (but, if I am right, I don't see how I could outrun Darmon anyway).

Comment: Good luck for the anticycl. ETNC (and don't forget it's very common than younger mathematicians outrun well-established specialists in the field). To answer your question about BK: yes I believe it is accessible, in two sense: (1) it is accessible by the means of algebraic number theory (and automorphic forms) while I believe
Perrin-Riou's conjecture, which contains as a very very special case 
 Leopoldt's is not (my original meaning), and (2)
I believe that the lower bound on Selmer in BK in any rank for automorphic Gal. rep. is doable(Chenevier and I did some cases in any rank years ago)